# showing parse error in blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am a beginner in laravel building a simple app in laravel. But something shows parse error in blade file I spent hours on id.Any help is appreciated.

```
<a class='Like'>{{Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id',$post->id)->first()
?Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id',$post->id)->first()->like == 1 ? '#liked#' 
 :'Like'}}</a>
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: this is not the correct way to display queries in blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two nested ternary operators, but I can see only one `:` symbol.